# AngularJS app server won't start with npm start

Tags: angularjs, npm

I was working on the AngularJS `angular-phonecat` tutorial on my MacBook, yesterday. It worked fine. (although `npm start` and `npm test` both required `sudo` to actually work, which is strange)

Today, I cloned the original repo onto my MacBookPro, ran `npm install`, and tried starting up with `npm start`, and I get errors:

```
$ npm start

... other scripts running ...

> http-server ./app -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1

events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:58:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1440:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:58:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start: `http-server ./app -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/TuzMacbookPro2017/.npm/_logs/2019-05-23T17_54_25_562Z-debug.log
```

Running just the last line of the script gives a similar though less verbose error:

```
$ http-server ./app -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1
events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:58:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1440:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:58:17)
```

To add insult to injury, when I run `sudo npm start` in the copy of the tutorial app on the computer I was working on yesterday, and then visit the url `localhost:8000` I get a `400` error. I can't image what would have changed since yesterday! `sudo npm test` launches the Karma tests without any problems on both computers (though the MacBook Pro doesn't require `sudo`).

Currently running npm 6.4.1 on both computers. The MacBook is on node 10.15.3, and the MacBookPro is on node 11.12.0

Even worse: I just now downloaded a new clone of the repo (straight from the angular website) and now the MacBook is giving this error when running `npm start`, with or without `sudo`:

```
> http-server ./app -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:8000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1270:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1318:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1451:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:61:10)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1297:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start: `http-server ./app -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Off-topic to your post, but as a heads up; as AngularJS is unlikely to be further developed with new features; it may not make sense to start learning it at this point. You're more likely to get a benefit from learning Angular, which, while it has the same name, is a different framework.

Comment: Thanks. I'm learning it to prep for an interview at a place that uses it a lot, and I did just check the job description and it definitely says AngularJS, but really thanks for the heads up!

Comment: You reverted my edit even though this question is clearly about angular and not angularjs, why?

Comment: Is it about AngularJS! I do not know Angular. I only know AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be in the `-a localhost` argument of the `httpserver` call. Removing it from the script in `package.json` fixed everything.